# scheduled Job to clear all objects in recycle bin

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, recycle-bin

I want to have batch and schedualed job to clear all my recycle bin every night.

I could write such job for on object, no problem.

```java
global class BatchDeleteRecycleBin implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {        
            return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT ID from  account where isDeleted = true ALL ROWS'); }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
          Database.emptyRecycleBin(scope); }  
    global finish .....
```

and wrote a scheduable class to run it. 
But How do I write a job to clear all my objects from the bin, not only the account? I dont want to write a job for every single object.  And also, regarding governance limits  - I understood I could only run batch for 2000 records, but my bin may have more than 2000 records a day.

I want a batch job, not to do it manually every day

Comment: any reason you need to do this every night versus waiting the 15 days for it to do this itself? Unfortunately, I think your only option is to explicitly query every object as there's no way to query across all objects at once.